# Android: How to parse same tags in SAX Parser?

Tags: android, web-services, parsing, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am trying to parse and get values from web service. The problem is that Web service has same element name tags which are creating problem to parse as I want to get their value but they are of same name So is difficult for me to mention them as localname.

```
 <countryBean>
        <id>236</id>
        <name>United State</name>
    </countryBean>
    <secutiryQuestion1>
        <id>2</id>
        <question>What was your dream job as a child?</question>
    </secutiryQuestion1>
    <secutiryQuestion2>
        <id>4</id>
        <question>What is the name, breed, and color of your pet?</question>
    </secutiryQuestion2>
    <stateBean>
        <country>236</country>
        <id>5</id>
        <name>California</name>
    </stateBean>
    <statusBean>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Active</name>
    </statusBean>
```

I want to get value of ID tag and other adjacent tag like name,question in different variables. and Here are 5 Id tags.

My class code is like

```
public class XmlParser extends DefaultHandler {

        public RestfullResponse tempResponse = null;
        String currentValue = null;
        int ServiceType =0;

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("countryBean")){
                tempResponse=new RestfullResponse();

                }           

        }


        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#endElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
            if(ServiceType == 1)
            {
                if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                    tempResponse.setCountryId(currentValue);
                }
                if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
                    tempResponse.setCountryName(currentValue);
                }

                if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                    tempResponse.setStateId(currentValue);
                }
                if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("question")){
                    tempResponse.setstateBean(currentValue);
                }

                if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Id")){
                    tempResponse.setStatusId(currentValue);
                }
                if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("requestSuccess")){
                    tempResponse.setStatus(currentValue);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        }

        public RestfullResponse getResponse(){
            return tempResponse;
        }
}
```

please Help to store them in

```
String CountryName= "";
String CountryId = "";
String Statename = "";
String StateId ="";
String Status = "";
String StatusId = "";
String Username ="";
String SecurityQuestion = "";
String SecurityQuestionId = "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain the `stack of root nodes`.

Take a variable of type `String root` and maintain a `stack of root element`.

**Inside startElement method:**

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException,
            IllegalArgumentException
{

   // call to abstract method
   onStartElement(namespaceURI, localName, qName, atts);

   // Keep the trace of the root nodes
   if (root.length() > 0)
   {
    root= root.concat(",");
   }
   root= root.concat(localName);
}
```

**Inside endElement method:**

```
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
{
   // remove the end element from stack of root elements
   int index = root.lastIndexOf(',');
   if (index > 0)
   {
    root= root.substring(0, index);
   }
   onEndElement(namespaceURI, localName, qName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add boolean variable isCountryBean;

```
boolean isCountryBean = false , isSecurityQuestion1 = false;
```

And in startElement(....) write:

```
if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("countryBean")){
    isCountryBean = true;
    // other stuff
} else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("secutiryQuestion1")){
    isSecurityQuestion1 = true;
    isCountryBean = false;
}
```

And in endElement(...) check:

```
if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
    if(isCountryBean){
        tempResponse.setCountryId(currentValue); 
     }
}
if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
    if(isCountryBean){
        isCountryBean = false;
        tempResponse.setCountryName(currentValue);

     }
}
```

Do it for other most outward tags. Hope it will help you.